# and(older(10),pk(A)) malleable if top-level, can it be top-level? EDIT: not malleable, was mistaken

Tags: script, miniscript

```
$ ./miniscript 

and(older(10),pk(A))
X    110.0000000000    37 and_v(v:pk(A),older(10)) and(older(10),pk(A))

and_v(v:pk(A),older(10))
      1 scriptlen=37 maxops=2 type=B safe=yes nonmal=yes dissat=no input=1n output=nonzero miniscript=and_v(v:pk(A),older(10))
<A> OP_CHECKSIGVERIFY 10 OP_CHECKSEQUENCEVERIFY
```

(the last line shows the compiled script because I added `printf("%s", Disassemble(ret->ToScript(COMPILER_CTX)).c_str());` to the command line-based tool output)

AFAICT nothing says that this cannot be top-level (but I may be missing something). It also says `nonmal=yes`, that this is not malleable.

The witness that is needed for this script to be successfully executed in the spending check is `[<A_signature>, <any-nonzero>]`, and of course the `CHECKSEQUENCEVERIFY` condition must pass. The `CHECKSIGVERIFY` will consume `<A_signature>`, and then `<any-nonzero>` will be checked as the sole item on the stack, that indicates success (after `CastToBool()`)

But `<any-nonzero>` can be just that, anything, and thus malleable.

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP_CHECKSEQUENCEVERIFY is a redefined OP_NOP code, so it cannot manipulate the stack - only abort or continue. In your script, that means it leaves the `10` on the stack, and no `<any-nonzero>` is necessary in the witness (and adding one would be a violation of the CLEANSTACK standardness rule).

Comment: Oh right, my mistake. It seems that I was looking at CHECKSIGVERIFY code that pops the arg, and thought that I was looking at CHECKSEQUENCEVERIFY.